# How to move file from one folder to another folder on remote sftp server providing the filename dynamically using Java Config?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, config, spring-integration-sftp

I am stuck with the problem. I have a folder om my sftp server with a file in it: *folder/file.txt* . What i'm trying to do is simply to move this file to another directory : *folder/subfolder/file.txt*. In documentation it was written that you simply need to use OutboundGateway with the MV command. That's ok but the main problem is that i don`t know exactly what would be the name of the file, so i need to provide this name dynamically. How can i do that?

```java
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "toSftpChannel",
        poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "60000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "-1"))
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
            new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File(localDirectory));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
    return source;
}

@Bean
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(getSftpSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("/folder");
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"));
    return fileSynchronizer;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
public SftpOutboundGateway moveFileHandler() {
     SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(getSftpSessionFactory(), "mv", "'folder/" + "file.txt" + "'");                                                  
        sftpOutboundGateway.setRenameExpression(new LiteralExpression("/folder/subfolder/" + "file.txt"));
        return sftpOutboundGateway;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using literal expressions, use a dynamic expression.

e.g. instead of

```
"'folder/" + "file.txt" + "'"
```

use

```
"'folder/' + headers['file_relativePath']"
```

and

```
sftpOutboundGateway.setRenameExpression(parser.parseExpression("'/folder/subfolder/' + headers['file_relativePath']";
```

(The relative path header is set up by the inbound adapter).

Comment: thanks a lot! It's actually works, but now it deletes other files in subfolder even though i set in file synchronizer  setDeleteRemoteFiles to false, am i doing smth wrong?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you mean by "other files". Please add more details.

Comment: i'm sorry to bother you, i've fixed this issue - the problem was that setDeleteRemoteFiles line was commented) Thank you for your help!!! It's highly appreciated!